# How to control application volume in WinXP

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, win32gui, win32-process

I would like to programatically control the volume of a particular application in WinXP.
I came to know abt one API `waveOutSetVolume()`, but it controls the application volume in Win Vista & Above, for XP it just affect the entire system volume.

Please advise how can we achieve this in XP?

Moreover how to Uncheck/Check the SYstem volume Mute check box as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, application-level audio levels are available from Vista OS, so XP has no ability to control it.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb945061.aspx

Your second question related to mute, you simply call waveOutSetVolume:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hey Thanks for your fast response. waveOutSetVolume(), function can make the volume level zero , which is having same effect like volume Mute, but I want to check/uncheck the checkbox for Mute in Volume control.

Comment: @AshishMittal, there is a bit of a hackier way. Use `SendInput` to send a `VK_VOLUME_MUTE` stroke. Some keyboards have volume buttons, so I guess Windows came prepared. It's been working for me on XP for having a keyboard shortcut to do it. Chances are this would affect an active application as well though. Perhaps you can send it to something like `DefWindowProc` to get the effect you need.

Comment: Thanks chris for you answer, but below mention are the roadblocks. 1.)I want not only to mute/unmute the machine volume , but also want to retireve the status of system volume mute/unmute. 2) My comp supplies its own keyboard to customers which does not have volume shortcuts buttons on it, so in this case the solution metioned by you will work?, please advice.